# How to write regular expressions in the Rules Grid in Abinitio

Tags: regex, data-quality, ab-initio

I have a regular expression which is working perfectly fine in the Sheet view in Abinitio ExpressIT but I am trying to do the same in the Rules Grid / Grid view

But I am not sure which function can I use in the Rules Grid. Tried with re_get_match and other string functions but no luck

While using re_get_match I am getting error as

> Can't cast utf8 string(int) to long

The regular expression I am using is r"[0-9+]+"

Please note the attribute is of string datatype and I am trying to validate the data in it by writing regular expressions which is working in sheet view but unable/not aware to do similar thing in rules grid

Comment: I don't know anything about ab initio, however it seems like the regex is working, but the cast of the result is not: Try wrapping the result of the regex method invocation in a function call that converts string to long. Consider also how your code behaves when the input contains no digits.